# How can you write a template function to add integers but concatenate strings and char types?

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to write a generic function(using templates) to add incase of ints and concatenate in case of chars or strings.
The following works fine with strings and ints however it doesnt work for chars.

```
string operator+(char a,char b)
{
        string c= string(1,a) + string(1,b);
        cout<<c;
        return c;
}


template<typename T>
void add(T a,T b)
{
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<a+b;
        cout<<endl;
}

int main()
{
        //string a="Stack",b=" Overflow"; //Works fine
        //int a=1,b=2; //Works fine
        char a='a',b='b'; //ISSUE HERE
        add(a,b);
        return 0;;
};
```

For chars it adds the ascii instead of concatenating.
Hence i overloaded operator '+'  for adding two char's.

```
string operator+(char a,char b)
{
        string c= string(1,a) + string(1,b);
        cout<<c;
        return c;
}
```

But seems like we cant even overload operator for adding two built in types.

```
typecast_overloading.cpp:5: error: âstd::string operator+(char, char)â must have an argument of class or enumerated type
```

So, how do i chars?

**EDIT:** This is not a duplicate of "Can i overload built in" types. I know i cannot. I just showed what i tried and what didnt work. May be the expected result can be achieved without overloading. And i am expecting these other ways.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Im not saying overloading is the way. Just saying overloading didnt work. It means the expected result can be achieved by some other means. Its not duplicate. Thanks

Comment: Not a good dupe, since the OP clearly wants to know how they could work around the constraint. Although the question could be changed to make this more explicit.

Comment: @anurag86: I think they might be retracted if you took the time to spruce up the question. And be sure to ask it in the context of "what is an alternative" rather than "why doesn't this work"? I've done the title for you. I upvoted the question simply because I found it interesting and there's no obvious duplicate, and the code snippet demonstrates good research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string operator+(char, char)` is not allowed by the C++ standard (you cannot overload operators for built-in types).

But you could *specialise* `void add(T a, T b)` for the `char` type:

```
template<>
void add(char a, char b)
{
    std::cout << a << b;
}
```

Comment: I prefer partial specialization.

Comment: Do you mean this specialized function should be present in addition to the templated add(). am i right? If so the compilation error is thrown: `add is not a template function`

Comment: @KhouriGiordano: Sounds good to me. Why not submit an answer?

Comment: @anurag86: Absolutely! But don't forget to put the specialisation below the generic template function.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative 1: Add an overload. It will be chosen over the template function because it is more specific.

```
string add( char a, char b )
{
    return string( 1, a ) + b;
}
```

Alternative 2: Use partial specialization. (Full-on template example)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
struct adder_t
{
    auto operator()(T const &a, T const &b) const
        -> decltype(a + b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
};

template<>
struct adder_t<char>
{
    std::string operator()(char a, char b) const
    {
        return std::string(1, a) + b;
    }
};

template< typename T >
auto add(T &&a, T &&b)
-> decltype(std::declval<adder_t<typename std::decay<T>::type>>()(a, b))
{
    adder_t<typename std::decay<T>::type> adder;
    return adder(std::forward<T>(a), std::forward<T>(b));
}

int main()
{
    std::string sa = "aaa", sb = "bbb";
    char ca = 'a', cb = 'b';
    int ia = 12, ib = 34;

    std::cout << add(sa, sb) << "\n";
    std::cout << add(ca, cb) << "\n";
    std::cout << add(ia, ib) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow i'm going to take a while to understand this as few things like decltype, &&,declval etc. are new to me (probably it belongs to c++11 or 14)

Comment: `decltype(expr)` gets the type as if (but not actually) evaluating `expr`. `declval<type>()` returns something that can be used as if it were an instance of `type` without actually constructing one. `T &&` becomes `T const &` when called with an lvalue and a non-const r-value when called with a temporary. `std::forward` will pass on a `T &&` if the function was called with one.

Comment: Now that I look at this again, the partial specialization is overkill for this case. In other situations, it might be the much simpler(!) option.